# I have an error Dockerfile with Django . How to solve it?

Tags: django, docker

Docker file doesn't work !

**Dockerfile**

```
   # Pull base image 
   FROM python 3.8

   # Set environment variables   
   ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
   ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

   # Set work directory
   WORKDIR /Django/bookstore/ 

   #Install dependencies
   COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /Django/
   RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

   #COPY project 
   COPY . /Django/bookstore/
```

**Docker-compose.yml**
version: '3.8'

```
   services:
    web:
     build: .
     command: python /Django/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
       - .:/Django
     ports:
       - 8000:8000
     depends_on:
       - db
    db:
     image: postgres:11
     volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  volumes:
   postgres_data:
```

About Django
My directory called **/Django/bookstore/**
Python version **3.8.5**

When I am coding Docker on cmd
I see an error

*docker-compose up -d --build*

```
    Building web
    ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 2: FROM requires either one or three arguments
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `FROM python:3.8`?

Comment: I have tried now however as same

Comment: Oh thanks it is working . I have missed space )

Answer (score 1):

See the [official python Docker image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), this is how a Docker base image is specified:

```
FROM python:3.8
```